# Web Api - httppost - The requested resource does not support http method Get after publish on production server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

when i add profile of supplier on localhost working fine. and API POSt method is working fine.
but after publish of project on server getting 400 error when i add profile of supplier.
and in response getting this.

**The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.**

with **400** status

i have attached images of errors.

Project url is :

https://localefood.maqssoft.com

test-user : supplier@gmail.com

password: a@123456A

This link has the same issue that i am looking for but not give the solution of problem.
https://forums.asp.net/t/2129791.aspx
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkqDq.png)

Comment: The error speaks clearly that you are calling an "ActionMethod" with "HttpPost" annotation so don't try to access this URL in the browser directly because this will send the request with HttpGet wrapper

Answer (score 0):

**Make a POST request with POSTMAN.**

1. List item Use the same URL as you did for the GET request steps above, but now choose POST to be the selected HTTP method.

[image]

2. Click the Body tab just under the URL, then choose the raw radio
   button and JSON (application/json) from the type dropdown menu:

[image]

3. You may note that a new Header gets automatically added to the
   request. Requests that send data need a header telling the API what
   kind of data is being sent. Click the Headers tab to see the
   Content-Type: application/json header:

[image]

> **Click Send.**
>
> If you have recently submitted a request you may not be asked to
>   authenticate again. If you get an Unauthorized error, request a new
>   access token and click Send again.